# How to make HttpClient sent safely in sonarqbue

Tags: c#, sonarqube, httpclient

Sonarqube scan our code saying "Make sure that this http request is sent safely." [image]

Is there a proper way to implement HttpClient aside from using the Singleton pattern? I also tried to use the ConfigureAwait(false) witch the sonarqube suggested. Here is the link https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3216
But sonarqube detect it and said the same error.

Comment: Did you read https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-4825 ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading here: https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/user-guide/security-reports/

This type of issue is a Security Hotspot and not a Vulnerability. It's telling you that this line should be reviewed manually and if it's okay deactivated for the current code.

---

**Beside**

Be careful when using .Result on a task. At the wrong place you could get a deadlock (for example, calling from the UI context)

A better implementation would be to wrap httpClient.PostAsync in an async method with .ConfigureAwait(false) on.

```
await _httpClient.PostAsync(apiURL, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Then, if needed, you call this method with .Result

ConfigureAwait(false) tells that the code after await has not to be run on the caller context (avoiding deadlocks).

Comment: Yeah I also tried ConfigureAwait(false) but the sonarqube detect it also. Anyways since the document just said that it should be MANUALLY review the application code.

Comment: It will be detected always, it's like an information

Comment: `reviewed manuall` https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-4825 may be helpful to link to in terms of what to review **for**.